# Find files from a folder when a specific word appears on at least a specific number of lines

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

How can I find the files from a folder where a specific word appears on more than 3 lines? I tried using recursive grep for finding that word and then using -c to count the number of lines where the word appears.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep

Comment: Please show your attempt and explain why it doesn't work. It sounds like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will recursively list the files in the current directory where `word` appears on more than 3 lines, along with the matches count for each file:

```
grep -c -r 'word' . | grep -v -e ':[0123]$' | sort -n -t: -k2
```

The final sort is not necessary if you don't want the results sorted, but I'd say it's convenient.

The first command in the pipeline (`grep -c -r 'word' .`) recursively finds every file in the current directory that contains `word`, and counts the occurrences for each file. The intermediate `grep` discards every count that is 0, 1, 2 or 3, so you just get counts greater than 3 (this is because `-v` in `grep(1)` inverts the sense of matching to select non-matching lines). The final sort step sorts the list according to the occurrences for each file; it sets the field delimiter to `:` and instructs `sort(1)` to do a numeric-based sorting using the 2nd field (the count) as the sort key.

Here's a sample output from some tests I ran:

```
./file1:4
./dir1/dir2/file3:5
./dir1/file2:8
```

If you just want the filenames without the match counts, you can use `sed(1)` to discard the `:count` portions:

```
grep -m 4 -c -r 'word' . | grep -v -e ':[0123]$' | sed -r 's/:[0-9]+$//'
```

As noted in the comments, if matches count is not important, in this case we can optimize the first `grep` with `-m 4`, which stops reading the file after 4 matching lines.

**UPDATE**

The solution above works fine up to a certain extent if used with small numbers, but it does not scale well for larger numbers. If you want to filter based on an arbitrary number, you can use `awk(1)` (and in fact it ends up being much more clean), like so:

```
grep -c -r 'word' . | awk -F: '$2 > 10'
```

The `-F:` argument to `awk(1)` is necessary; it instructs `awk(1)` to separate fields by `:` rather than the default (whitespace and tab). This solution generalizes well to any number.

Again, if matches count doesn't matter and all you want is to get a list of the filenames, do this instead:

```
grep -c -r 'word' . | awk -F: '$2 > 10 { print $1 }'
```

Comment: You could possibly optimize by adding `-m 4` to the `grep -c` command.  It will terminate on the fourth match already, instead of reading through to the end of the file.  (Not sure how portable this is; works as expected on Linux, at the very least.)

Comment: @tripleee Yes, you could do that, thanks for suggesting. But this improvement comes at the cost of precision loss in the match count; if it is important to get the matches count, this is certainly not acceptable. But if the count is not important (as in the last command I suggest), then it's a good optimization.

Comment: What should I do if I want a to show files where 'word' appears on a number of lines more than 10, for example 26?